# Regulator that can handle voltage on its output

Tags: voltage-regulator

I need a voltage regulator for a project which will handle a voltage on its output pin with no input. (The GND pin may still be connected.) Most devices don't seem to be able to handle this. Are there any which can?

Comment: Toss a diode in series with the output - Hey-Presto, any regulator will now work!

Comment: @Fake Name, you gonna tell your 3.3V micro to work at 2.6V?

Comment: Then use a Schottky, or an adjustable reg.

Comment: @Fake Name, a diode has further issues; namely, increased drop out voltage, and making the output less stable with load current. Also, there's the extra cost, and surface area. With an adjustable regulator, you have to have feedback resistors, further increasing cost and size. And not all adjustable regulators - especially LDOs - will be happy with a diode in the feedback loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You sometimes see a diode connected from the output of a regulator back to the input, such that under normal powered operation, the diode is reverse biased. If you remove the input power, the diode can conduct, and clamps the regulator input voltage to not more than a diode drop below the output voltage.

Answer (score 3):

Which regulators have you seen that don't allow that?

It's actually a requirement of voltage regulators that they can handle a voltage on the output with no input voltage! Suppose that you have a 12V regulator with a large capacitor on the output, which is generally the case. As soon as the input supply to the regulator is removed, the capacitor on the output will discharge into the regulator output, starting at 12V.

Comment: That's not strictly correct.  Check out this datasheet, http://www.national.com/ds/LP/LP2985.pdf, page 15, reverse output-input voltage.  Most regulators have some sort of diode, but it can be easy to exceed the power rating on that diode.  In those cases, an external diode is required.   Reducing the caps on the output can help this diode situation, but sometimes that can't be avoided.

Comment: It does apply to most of the popular regulators, though, such as the LM78xx.

Comment: I've encountered it enough where I always check the datasheets.  Better safe than sorry.  It does appear to be more common on the newer regulators, regulators with lower current specs, and LDO's.  You're right that the 78XX series does not appear to mention it in the datasheets.  I just have to mention, however, that I haven't used a 78XX in over 15 years-- although given the types of people who are normally on this web site I'm the odd man out.

Comment: I'd also be fairly wary about saying it's a "requirement of voltage regulators".  Generally true, but if you assume incorrectly very bad things can happen.

Answer (score 0):

An elegant solution to this problem would be to use a regulator with a shutdown pin, and have some sort of undervoltage limit derived from the input voltage controlling this shutdown pin.